# Shadowsocks configuration to access internet on Iranian restricted networks

Tags: server, proxy, devops, vpn, system-administration

As you know, the Iranian government restricts internet access.
You should know that Iran datacenters have internet and if you have Iranian vps and external vps you can almost always access the internet.

(pic 1) I setup shadowsocks with cloak and IP forwarding on my Iranian VPS. It works fine, but iOS clients cannot access the cloak using shadowsocks, so I must find another way.
[image]

(pic 2) I came up with the idea of setting up shadowsocks + clock on the Iranian VPS and connecting to it via a proxy.
Shadowsocks will start and listen on port 1080 when you run it on the server.
[image]

What is the best way to setup proxy to let my client connect to the 1080 port (using username and password)?
If you have a better idea, please share it with me.

Comment: Please read the tag description for [tag:vpn].

Comment: Did you try to use https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shadowrocket/id932747118 ? According to https://github.com/cbeuw/Cloak/issues/170 it may works with cloak+shadowrocket on ios